# How to declare a type of (string, IDictionary<string, object>)

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables

I am fixing a bug on a legacy system. It has a function with return type `(string, IDictionary<string, object>)`. I cannot change the method signature. I want to declare a variable of method return type. I tried this but its giving me an error.

```
var sqlQuery = new (string, IDictionary<string, object>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [value tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) type (available in C# 7.0 and later) and you can either use target-typed new expression ([since C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)) to fill it with default values:

```cs
(string, IDictionary<string, object>) sqlQuery = new();
```

or using `default`:

```cs
(string, IDictionary<string, object>) sqlQuery = default;
```

or provide values of needed types:

```cs
var sqlQuery = (someString, someDictionary);
// or
var sqlQuery = ((string)null, (IDictionary<string, object>)null);
```

Or just use result of the method returning the tuple:

```cs
var sql = MethodReturningTuple();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) can have multiple data types and that is what the function returns in your case.

you can create a var

```
 var sqlQuery = method();
```

while debugging, you can verify that data is filled properly into the tuple.

or you can create specific type per method return

```
(string, IDictionary<string, object>) sqlQuery = method();
```

It is better to use var as it can change with method signature. Having said that, every pro has cons, code can fail if the type is changed. C# is type safe and (hopefully) compile will detect the type change.